# how to do a delta backup using wal-g

Tags: postgresql

Can someone help me with command line command or config to create delta backup following a base backup using `wal-g`?

The base backup is done using the following command:

```
AWS_REGION=xxx WALG_S3_PREFIX=s3://xxx/delta_wal wal-g backup-push /var/lib/pgsql/10/data
```

I see config like `WALG_DELTA_MAX_STEPS` and `WALG_DELTA_ORIGIN`, but I am not able to figure out how to use them to create a delta backup.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `WALG_DELTA_MAX_STEPS` to a number greater than 0. I'd recommend 6. This will instruct WAL-G that it can push delta-backups if they do not create chains longer than 6 delta backups from one backup.